# Dynamic Field selection in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-9

How can i define a dynamic selection field where the user can add new  items that are not predefined
this code define a static selection field:

score:field.selection([('key1','value1').....],string='score'),

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to create a many2one field:

```
class yourmodule_score_rel(models.Model):
     _name = 'yourmodel.score.rel'

     name = fields.Char('Score')
```

And in your module's class:

```
score_id = fields.Many2one('yourmodel.roles.rel', string='Score')
```